# How to modify useState array one by one in mapped promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-promise

I have
`const [items, setItems] = useState<any[]>(itemsB.map(() => ({ loading: true })));`
and

```
itemsB.map(async (itemB: any, index: number) => {
    searchItems(itemB).then(result => {
        const newItems = [...items]; // Ref A
        newItems[index] = result;
        setItems(newItems);
    })
})
```

Because the inner function is an async fetch, items come back in an unpredictable order, and I want to add them to `items` as soon as they're ready, changing the placeholder loading object with the actual result. This almost does that, but the `items` referenced at Ref A does not update, so it cycles through changing each thing and then at the end only the last item to have been retrieved appears.

If I do a `Promise.all().then()`, it waits until all items are retrieved to execute the `then` part, so I'm wondering how to set items as they are resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls made to setItems are batched to optimize performance. If the previous state relies on the current state, use the overloaded version of setItems which takes the previousState as the first argument.

```
searchItems(itemB).then(result => {
        setItems(items => {
                  const newItems = [...items]; // Ref A
                  newItems[index] = result;
                  return newItems;
        });
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Had no idea about that overloaded version of setItems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work:

```
itemsB.forEach(async (itemB: any) => {
    searchItems(itemB).then(result => {        
        setItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, result]);
    });
});
```

Note: this should not be in the render function. you should place that in componentDidMount/Update or useEffect hook.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the async library to help you to solve the problem as below:

```js
import eachOf from 'async/eachOf';

// assuming items is an array of async items
async.eachOf(itemsB, async (itemB: any, index: number, callback: ReturnType<string | void>) => {

    // Perform operation on itemB here.
    console.log('Processing item ' + itemB);
    
    try {
      const result = await searchItems(itemB);
      
      const newItems = [...items]; // Ref A
      // Settting-up new items
      newItems[index] = result;
      setItems(newItems);
      
      callback();
    }catch(e) {
      callback(e)
    }
}, function(err) {
    // If any of the item processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      // All processing will now stop.
      console.log('An item failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All items have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```